# In Python how do I use a class method without passing an instance to it?

Tags: python, methods, module

So I have a common module which contains processing functions for numbers and types of data I am using. I want to be able to include it like `from common import common` (or better yet just `import common`) and use functions like `common.howLongAgo(unixTimeStamp)`

What is required to do this in my common module?. Common is a module consisting of a class 'common'.

Comment: Why are these functions on a class in the first place?  If they don't need `self`, why not move them to the module scope?

Comment: To get them out of my main python file

Comment: To achieve this, you wouldn't need to put them in a class.  Just move them to a module and leave them at module level.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Ways of exposing methods in a python module:

module `foo.py`:

```
def module_method():
    return "I am a module method"

class ModClass:
     @staticmethod
     def static_method():
         # the static method gets passed nothing
         return "I am a static method"
     @classmethod
     def class_method(cls):
         # the class method gets passed the class (in this case ModCLass)
         return "I am a class method"
     def instance_method(self):
         # An instance method gets passed the instance of ModClass
         return "I am an instance method"
```

now, importing:

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo.module_method()
'I am a module method'
>>> foo.ModClass.static_method()
'I am a static method'
>>> foo.ModClass.class_method()
'I am a class method'
>>> instance = ModClass()
>>> instance.instance_method()
'I am an instance method'
```

If you want to make class method more useful, import the class directly:

```
>>> from foo import ModClass
>>> ModClass.class_method()
'I am a class method'
```

You can also `import ... as ...` to make it more readable:

```
>>> from foo import ModClass as Foo
>>> Foo.class_method()
'I am a class method'
```

Which ones you should use is somewhat a matter of taste. My personal rule of thumb is:

- Simple utility functions that generally act on things like collections, or perform some computation or fetch some resource should be module methods
- Functions related to a class but that do not require either a class or an instance should be static methods
- Functions that are related to a class, and will need the class for comparison, or to access class variable should be class methods.
- Functions that will act on an instance should be instance method.

Comment: Is it common code practice to have methods exposed at the module scope like this? Regardless - it worked so thanks.

Comment: Decorating your class methods with `@classmethod` is a lot cleaner

Comment: It's common enough. The standard library has a few examples. the `os` module being one.

Comment: I actually prefer to use `@staticmethod` I'll amend. To reflect all three options.

Comment: If I use the first example, a module method it works. The class method says I must give it a common instance as the first argument. the instance method works.

Comment: @Supernovah have a look at the amendments I just made. I forgot to add the staticmethod decorator.

Comment: I think `staticmethod` is rarely ever useful in Python.  It cannot access a class, nor an instance, so why is this method in a class at all?  I know there are use cases, but they are pretty exceptional.

Answer (score 1):

if you have module common.py and function is in class common

```
class common(object):
    def howLongAgo(self,timestamp):
          some_code
```

then you should change your method to be static method whit decorator @staticmethod

```
class common(object):
    @staticmethod
    def howLongAgo(timestamp): # self goes out
          some_code
```

This way you do not need to change whole class and you can still use self.howLongAgo in class

Answer (score -1):

```
class Test(object):
    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls):
        return "class method"

test = Test()
print test.class_method()

[callen@odin scar]$ python ~/test.py
class method
```

The above is the standard way of doing classmethods using modern Python objects, not the old-style classes.

Alternately, you might mean a staticmethod:

```
class Test(object):
    @staticmethod
    def static_method():
        return "static method"

test = Test()
print test.static_method()
[callen@odin scar]$ python ~/test.py
static method
```

Use whichever makes more sense to you for your problem. Staticmethods should usually be separated into their own independent functionality, the use of a class is superfluous there.

Cf.
http://pyvideo.org/video/880/stop-writing-classes

Comment: Yes but the problem is that upon doing `test = Test()` you are creating an instance. This is what I want to avoid.