# Pyscript using classes in the Python source code

Tags: python, pyscript

I am trying to rewrite the [Polyglot - Piratical PyScript](https://docs.pyscript.net/2023.09.1.RC2/beginning-pyscript/) application using in `main.py` a `Pirate` class instead of the original `translate_english` function.

**`pyscript.json`**

```
{
    "packages": ["arrr"]
}
```

**`index.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
      <title> Polyglot - Piratical PyScript</title>
      <script type="module" src="https://pyscript.net/snapshots/2023.09.1.RC2/core.js"></script>
      </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Polyglot    ➡️ ‍☠️</h1>
    <p>Translate English into Pirate speak...</p>
    <input type="text" id="english" placeholder="Type English here..." />
    <button py-click="Pirate.translate_english">Translate</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script type="py" src="./main.py" config="./pyscript.json"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Where I have replaced the original code

```
<button py-click="translate_english">Translate</button>
```

with

```
<button py-click="Pirate.translate_english">Translate</button>
```

**`main.py`**

```
import arrr
from pyscript import document


class Pirate:
    def __init__(self):
        self.input_text = document.querySelector("#english")
        self.english = self.input_text.value
        self.output_div = document.querySelector("#output")
        self.translate_english()

    def translate_english(self):
        self.output_div.innerText = arrr.translate(self.english)
```

The error I get is the following:

[image]

Please help.

**EDITED 1**

But replacing in **`index.html`** the line

```
<button py-click="Pirate.translate_english">Translate</button>
```

with

```
<button py-click="Pirate2.__init__">Translate</button>
```

and in **`main.py`**

```
class Pirate2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.input_text = document.querySelector("#english")
        self.english = self.input_text.value
        self.output_div = document.querySelector("#output")
        self.output_div.innerText = arrr.translate(self.english)
```

Then works:

[image]

**EDITED 2**

Replacing in **`index.html`** the line

```
<button py-click="Pirate.translate_english">Translate</button>
```

with

```
<button py-click="translate">Translate</button>
```

and in **`main.py`**

```
import arrr
from pyscript import document


class Pirate:
    def __init__(self):
        self.input_text = document.querySelector("#english")
        self.english = self.input_text.value
        self.output_div = document.querySelector("#output")
        self.translate_english()

    def translate_english(self):
        self.output_div.innerText = arrr.translate(self.english)

def translate(event):
    pirate = Pirate()
    pirate.translate_english()
```

Then works:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python how do I use a class method without passing an instance to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934134/in-python-how-do-i-use-a-class-method-without-passing-an-instance-to-it)

Comment: Basically you don't have an instance of the `Pirate` class and yet are calling a method `translate_english` on it. I don't know what you are trying to do there but I don't think pyscript will automatically instantiate a class because you are using its method.

Comment: About your first comment @AbdulAzizBarkat , that would work with normal python scripts, but what about pyscript?

About your second comment, I'm thinking about more complex python scripts working with encapsulation. See my edited question.

Comment: You are misusing classes the way you are using them there. `py-click="Pirate2.__init__"` will call the `__init__` method of the class but will pass the event as the first argument which should usually be the instance. If you really want to use classes over there for some reason (I don't really see the need in your specific usecase) instantiate the class first and use the instances method or create a static method.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat you say you don't see the point in using classes. This code is a silly example to present the problem. How would you organise the Python code if it had lots of functions?

I've modified `main.py` to include a translate method where the `Pirate` class is instantiated. In `index.html` I've modified the line `<button py-click="translate">Translate</button>`. See **EDITED 2**.